# Correct sentence construction during documenting a user activity

Tags: grammar, indian-english

I am preparing some user guidance document and documenting how a system behaves. During that documentation I am facing some difficulties to express a user activity.

Can some one please explain Which one is correct/more appropriate and why other is wrong?

1. Click on "Yes", system process the request.
2. Click on "Yes", system **processes** the request.
3. Clicking on "Yes", system process the request.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your 3 options:
- "The system" is 3rd person singular (it, he, she) so requires processes as the correct conjugation (not process, which goes with I, you, we, or they).  You should also use the article "the"
- You also need a link between the user action and the result (a semicolon could work in your 2nd option, but not really for a user guide when you want to make the link very clear)

I would say (in order of preference for a user guide):
- Click on "Yes" to initiate/start the {system process, request}
- To initiate the {system process, request}, click on "Yes"
- Clicking on "Yes" initiates the {system process, request}
- When you click on "Yes", the system processes the request (When provides the link, but you can also use After or Once)

Note - process is also a noun so you can say "The system process is very user-friendly" or "The system processes occur on the server (or client) side"